# Redirecting http request to two different weblogic servers using the Weblogic proxy and Apache2

Tags: apache, weblogic, weblogic9.x

I've read previous posts like "Redirecting https requests to two different weblogic servers using the Weblogic proxy and Apache2". But I have a different situation and I don't think I'm understanding this to well.
I have an Apache 2 server (server1) that will receive http request for my application. Then I have two more servers (server2 and server3) with Web Logic 9.2 runing on ports 7000 (server1) and 8000 (server2).
I want the users to enter appname.domain.com and be redirected between the two web logic servers, always keeping appname.domain.com (this is hidding servername:port from URL).
How can I manage to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Jhon.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Apache HTTP Server plug-in* provided by BEA/Oracle to front and load balance request to your application.

I'd use a virtual host here, something like this:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/test/VirtualHost1"
    ServerName appname.domain.com   
    <IfModule mod_weblogic.c> 
    #... WLS parameter ...
    WebLogicCluster 192.168.1.100:7000,192.168.1.200:8000
    # Example: MatchExpression *.jsp <some additional parameter>
    MatchExpression *.jsp PathPrepend=/test
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

This config should balance requests to http://appname.domain.com/
to http://192.168.1.100:7000/test and http://192.168.1.200:8000/test.

Refer to the official documentation for all the details:

- [Installing and Configuring the Apache HTTP Server Plug-In](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/plugins/apache.html)
- [Parameters for Web Server Plug-Ins](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/plugins/plugin_params.html)
- and also [Thread: Installing and Configuring the Apache HTTP Server Plug-In](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4097678)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've already do that. My problem is that I want to keep  http://appname.domain.com in the URL, but in fact the URL is changed to  http://192.168.1.100:7000/test and http://192.168.1.200:8000/test.

Thank you!

Comment: @Jhon What do you mean by "I want to keep appname.domain.com in the URL", I don't understand. At what level?

Comment: Configure appname.domain.com as the frontend host

Answer (score 0):

Install an Webgate on HHTp server incase of Orcle, which will do the reverse proxy and hide the server name.